# Bootstrap column issue

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm having an issue with a couple background images. I have two columns in a row. Each column has another div in it which holds the background image. For some odd reason the image on the right is lower than the left. I can't seem to figure out why.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
        <div class="signs-box">
            <p>text</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
        <div class="person-box">
            <h2>title</h2>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And the css:

```
.signs-box {
    background-image: url("/images/image1.jpg");
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    min-height: 595px;
}

.person-box {
    background-image: url("/images/image2.jpg");
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    min-height: 595px;
}
```

Comment: How wide are the images? 

Also Change "<p>text</p>" to "<div>text</div>" p tags add an additional break implicitly. 

This question would be easier to answer if you had a demo of the issue.

Comment: `col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6` is quite redundant; see https://github.com/twbs/bootlint/wiki/E029

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would be because of the differing top margins set on a `<p>` and and an `<h2>` in bootstrap. This affects the position of the parent container. You can fix it by setting it, like so:

```
.signs-box p, .person-box h2{
     margin-top:0; 
}
```

[**See the difference here**](http://www.bootply.com/k94ZeMKnoO)

Answer (score 0):

It's likely the p and the h2 have different margins, and they are pushing their parent div downward, not just positioning themselves within it.